# Hierarchical Queries "START WITH" with where clause behavior

Tags: database, oracle, hierarchy, connect-by

I came across a query during work and could not figure out how exactly it works. What the query does is look for all the parents to a person that are its parent today.

Now the trick here is that each parent child relationship has a duration for which it is valid.

Take this data set as a reference:

> GrandParent is parent of Father from 01-01-2012 to 02-02-2015
>
> Father is parent of Child from 01-01-2012 to 02-02-2011
>
> Child is just the lowest level person
>
> NewFather is parent of Child from 01-01-2012 to 02-02-2014

now the list of parents valid today for Child should consist only of `NewFather`

to get the list, previously we used this SQL:

```
SELECT connect_by_root per_id2 AS per_id2,
       per_id1,
       LEVEL                   AS per_level,
       n.entity_name
FROM   ci_per_per pp,
       ci_per_name N
WHERE  N.per_id = per_id1
       AND start_dt <= SYSDATE
       AND ( end_dt IS NULL
              OR end_dt >= SYSDATE )
START WITH per_id2 = :personID
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2;
```

where `personID` is a binded variable

this query did not work because the where clause behavior is such that it first gets all the records and then checks for the non-join conditions (checks for start date and end date). This results in it giving list of parents as `NewFather, GrandParent` which is completely WRONG!

Thus, the query was changed to the Following:

```
SELECT connect_by_root per_id2 AS per_id2,
       per_id1,
       LEVEL                   AS per_level,
       n.entity_name
FROM   ci_per_per pp,
       ci_per_name N
WHERE  N.per_id = per_id1
       AND start_dt <= SYSDATE
       AND ( end_dt IS NULL
              OR end_dt >= SYSDATE )
START WITH per_id2 = (SELECT per_id
                      FROM   ci_acct_per
                      WHERE  per_id = :personID
                             AND pp.start_dt <= SYSDATE
                             AND ( pp.end_dt IS NULL
                                    OR pp.end_dt >= SYSDATE ))
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2;
```

Now what I don't understand is:

> how can a where condition in the start with clause affect the behavior of the query in such a manner?

Another thing that I dislike about this query is that it uses a completely unrelated table named `ci_acct_per` which simply has a column of `per_id` in it for each person in `ci_per_per`.

> Can we do better? Is a cleaner approach available for the fixing the original query?

**UPDATE**

This query works only if traveling higher in the hierarchy and not if we are looking for children. However, this query never looks for children and is not supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you right, but why not:

```
SELECT connect_by_root per_id2 AS per_id2,
       pp.per_id1,
       LEVEL                   AS per_level,
       n.entity_name
FROM   (select * 
        from ci_per_per
       where start_dt <= SYSDATE
       AND ( end_dt IS NULL
              OR end_dt >= SYSDATE )) pp join
       ci_per_name N on N.per_id = pp.per_id1         
START WITH per_id2 = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR pp.per_id1 = pp.per_id2;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c092/1)

---

**Update** Thanks to @user1395 [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3973/1):

It's hard to explain how come the strange query works because it doesn't...

What really happens is that the `START WITH` clause uses per_id2 which is the "father of" column, so if there are more than one (one isn't relevant to sysdate) you still need **not** to start with it.
In other words it doesn't start from "child" but from "child" fathers - "father" and "newfather".

So, either use @user1395 suggestion of having date logic in both the `connect by` clause to stop when a father isn't relevant, and `start with` clause to make only the relevant father available, or remove all unrelevant fathers on the first place (as in my former suggestion) or "start with" the "child" and not its fathers:

```
select * from (
SELECT connect_by_root per_id1 AS per_id2,
       per_id1,
       LEVEL                   AS per_level,
       n.entity_name
FROM   ci_per_per pp,
       ci_per_name N
WHERE  N.per_id = per_id1       
START WITH per_id1 = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2 AND start_dt <= SYSDATE
       AND ( end_dt IS NULL
              OR end_dt >= SYSDATE ))
where per_id1 <> per_id2;
```

[Another sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3973/17)

Comment: now I remember suggesting something similar to the person who wrote the new query before he wrote it and then he came up with that weird query but I forgot all of this! However, I would still like to know how his query is working!

Comment: I have no idea... it's even stranger- this also works http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9e68/10

Comment: hahahaha! I guess the where clause implementation for the main sql is buggy! Or wait as per the above answer, it might be the way `START WITH` is implemented!

Answer (score 1):

You could use date logic inside connect by clause.

```
SELECT connect_by_root per_id2 AS per_id2,
       per_id1,
       LEVEL                   AS per_level,
       n.entity_name
FROM   ci_per_per pp,
       ci_per_name N
WHERE  N.per_id = per_id1
START WITH per_id2 = :personID AND 
                         SYSDATE BETWEEN start_dt AND NVL(end_dt,SYSDATE)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR per_id1 = per_id2 AND 
                         SYSDATE BETWEEN start_dt AND NVL(end_dt,SYSDATE);
```

This will stop climbing up when there are no valid parents for the current date.

Comment: actually i need all the columns that i am using in my query, it just that the error is only effecting the columns u have suggested

Comment: moreover, your approach is only working for 1 level of hierarchy and not for multi level!!!

Comment: That's what I thought you wanted. I was confused by your statements: "What the query does is look for all the parents to a person that are its parent today.", "now the list of parents valid today for Child should consist only of NewFather", "This results in it giving list of parents as NewFather, GrandParent which is completely WRONG!" - I somehow thought GrandParent was parent of NewFather, sorry.

Comment: no sweat bro! just change your answer appropriately or delete your answer for the sake of the site :)

Comment: @user1395, you havn't used the date logic in the `connect by` clause but in the `start with` clause exactly like my wierd example. See that if you remove the logic from the `start with` clause you'll get wrong results... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9e68/42

Comment: @A.B.Cade Thanks, I saw what you did and added 'start with' clause as well - I think date logic in my example is necessary both in 'start with' and 'connect by' if there are three levels and no date valid relationship on second level. I've modified your sqlfiddle example (grandfather is parent of new father and has its own parent, but grandfather-new father is not date valid) see [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3973/1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3973/1)

Comment: @user1395, mmmm... now this explains it all... the wierd query in of OP doesn't work as well! now it makes sense